# How to change the window size with each time in C#

Tags: c#, user-experience

Its that I am developing an application in C# and I have used three tab controls there. The problem is I can not change the actual window size of the application when I change to another tab because I do not need such big window for that and when I change back to the previous one it should go back to previous size.

Comment: I personally feel that constantly changing the window size would not provide a very pleasant user experience, if they maximize (unless you don't let them) then they will get a full-screen window anyway. I would suggest setting the window size to the maximum you need and just have tabs that don't fill the full window with content all the time

Comment: Do not use tab control. Use panels and show/hide them via buttons. You simply have to set autosize and AutoSizeMode property of Form.

Comment: Is this WinForms or WPF?

Answer (score 2):

In my opinion you should not change the size of the window when the selected tab changes. Design your window in such a way that you don't need to resize it.

Redesign your tabs in such a way that they always consume the same size so you don't need to resize the window.

I would not expect, as a user, that the window size changes because it may give you a bad user experience.

Comment: I get the point but its a project and I was asked to do it. So, can you please help?

Comment: Try to redesign you tabs in such a way that the consume allway the same size. So you don't need to resize the window. Does that help you?

Comment: I tried that but you see the contents of one tab take so much space and the others don't and I have to keep those that way.

Answer (score 1):

i think you want this:

```
    private void tabControl1_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (tabControl1.SelectedTab.Text == "tabPage1")
        { 
        // rezise tabcontrol
        }
    }
```

although i dont think its user-friendly

Comment: @shihab13rocks see my edit, now using selectedIndexChanged, this works (for me)